# Is it possible to use two different Struts versions in the same Tomcat?

Tags: security, tomcat, struts2, struts

I'm going to upgrade Tomcat 6 to 7.

Currently in Tomcat 6 I'm using different contexts with different Struts versions. One context uses Struts 1 & another one uses Struts 2.

However, I'm merging contexts as `ROOT.war` in Tomcat 7. How to use Struts 1 & 2 in same war?

Also how to use the Struts2 security properties in the same WAR?

Comment: *struts2 security properties* - What? There are other ways besides deploying your war as root.war to achieve root context.

Answer (score 1):

The Struts 1 servlet is only a servlet and can be configured in `web.xml` with a context. You can use different action extention to map servlet and struts2 filter, struts1 defaults to `.do` and struts2 defaults to `.action`. But if you want to map struts2 as `/*` then better to add an exclude pattern to struts2 configuration.

```xml
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value=".*\.do$"/>
    ...
</struts>
```

The value is regex pattern, you can try yourself, but the current expression will exclude everything that ends with `.do`.